# Get backbone model name

Tags: backbone.js

Given a Backbone model or backbone model instance, I would like to get the model's name. For instance:

```
var p = new Person(); // Person is a BB model.
console.log(p.getNameAsStringOrSomething()); //Prints "Person"
```

Thats it, pretty simple :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
model.constructor.name
```

However, it will not work if you have a minifier like Jammit, the constructor will change after packaging and also on chrome you it might not work

I would suggest you to have a class property then you can get the name by simply using

```
var obj = model.constructor.propertyName
```

Comment: `constructor.name` also doesn't work in some versions of IE (AFAIK). I think your `propertyName` approach is the only reliable way to get the name.